# Clear fastcgi_cache cache if Nginx $arg is true

Tags: caching, nginx, fastcgi

I'm using Nginx and I have the problem that I need to clear the fastcgi_cache on demand.

If an argument is passed to the website ($arg_empty_smarty_cache), then a script should run. Or something should happen that will clear the whole cache folder. Right now I created a new location to make this work, but that solution is not good enough.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is [the `proxy_cache_purge` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_purge) that can do the trick, but it's available only in the commercial version.

Comment: Actually that wouldn't work either. proxy_cache_purge is not available inside an "if". The same with "fastcgi_cache_purge" (http, server, location). So an $arg can't match

Comment: @sebastiannm the `map` directive is better alternative to `if` blocks. The example in the configuration shows how to use it with [`fastcgi_cache_purge`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_cache_purge), you just need a map on your `$arg_` variable.